# Convert minutes in hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to convert minutes in hoursa format but my solution add second also, can any one help to remove second

Current Result: 02:02:00

Need Result Like this: 02:02

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(12), DATEADD(minute,122, 0), 108)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEADD(minute,122, 0), 108)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(12), DATEADD(minute,122, 0), 108),1,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

For less precision, modify the size of the `varchar`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(5), DATEADD(minute,122, 0), 108)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @temp_date datetime=dateadd(millisecond,-datepart(millisecond,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)


select cast(dateadd(second,-datepart(second,@temp_date),@temp_date) AS time)
```